# BigQuery does CROSS EACH WITH ALL for some reason

Tags: google-bigquery

my left join with subquery has a plan that works for way too long.

```
column_01,....column_20
FROM my_table
$840
FROM __stage18_output
$2980 := 1
between($4243, $4140, $4141)
$4140 := $730, $4141 := $731, $4142 := $732, $4143 := $733, $4144 := $734, $4145 := $735, $4146 := $736, $4147 := $737, $4148 := $738, $4149 := $739, $4150 := $740, $4151 := $741, $4152 := $742, $4153 := $743, $4154 := $744, $4155 := $745
CROSS EACH WITH ALL
$4140, $4141, $4142, $4143, $4144, $4145, $4146, $4147, $4148, $4149, $4150, $4151, $4152, $4153, $4154, $4155
TO __stage19_output
```

does any one know what `CROSS EACH WITH ALL` mean here?

Comment: providing the query would be much more helpful than posting the translated step join condition. Well, there are several join conditions or several tables involved. For each a join is calculated: `CROSS EACH WITH ALL `. There is no way BigQuery can use hashes to solve this join.#  `CROSS ALL WITH ALL ` is a cross join.

Comment: `EACH WITH ALL` means a broadcast join, whereas `EACH WITH EACH` means a hash join in BigQuery.